# Cant pass last inserted ID to another activity, Intent always returns default value

Tags: java, android, android-intent, insert, android-database

I am trying to pass the id that my method "InserIntoRegSintomas" returns, but it seems is passes always "0" the default value on this line:

```
final long id = intent2.getIntExtra("myExtras", 0);
```

**Where i try to get the id and pass it by intent to the next activity:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_intensidade_picker);

    CirclePicker = (HoloCircleSeekBar) findViewById(R.id.picker);

    Skip = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSkip);
    Seguinte = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);

    Seguinte.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            dal = new DAL(IntensidadePicker.this);
            dal.connect(DBAccessMode.READ);

            Intent intent = getIntent();
            Sintoma s = (Sintoma)intent.getSerializableExtra("sampleObject");

            s.setIntensidade(CirclePicker.getValue());
            dal.insertIntoRegSintomas(s);
            long id = s.getId();


            Intent intent2 = new Intent(IntensidadePicker.this, Motivo_sintoma.class);
            intent2.putExtra("myExtras", id);
            startActivity(intent2);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Where i get the intent passed value:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_motivo_sintoma);

    android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar =  getSupportActionBar() ;
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#1a212c")));

    //gets oldFruits.
    Intent intent2 = getIntent();
    final long id = intent2.getIntExtra("myExtras", 0);

    Skip = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSkip);
    Next = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
    btnAlcool = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    btnAnsiedade = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
    btnCafe = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
    btnStress = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton4);
    btnTempo = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton5);
    btnCansaco = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton6);
    btnSono= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton7);
    btnRemover = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton8);
    btnAdicionar = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton9 );

    dal = new DAL(Motivo_sintoma.this);
    dal.connect(DBAccessMode.READ);

    Skip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Motivo_sintoma.this, TomouMedicacao.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    btnAlcool.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View button) {
            btnAlcool.setSelected(!button.isSelected());
            if (button.isSelected()) {
                dal.inserIntoRelMotivos(id,1);
            } else {

            }
        }
    });

    btnAnsiedade.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View button) {
            btnAnsiedade.setSelected(!button.isSelected());
            if (button.isSelected()) {
                dal.inserIntoRelMotivos(id,2);
            } else {

            }
        }
    });

    btnCafe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View button) {
            btnCafe.setSelected(!button.isSelected());
            if (button.isSelected()) {
                dal.inserIntoRelMotivos(id,3);
            } else {

            }
        }
    });

    btnStress.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View button) {
            btnStress.setSelected(!button.isSelected());
            if (button.isSelected()) {
                dal.inserIntoRelMotivos(id,4);
            } else {

            }
        }
    });

    btnTempo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View button) {
            btnTempo.setSelected(!button.isSelected());
            if (button.isSelected()) {
                dal.inserIntoRelMotivos(id,5);
            } else {
            }
        }
    });

    btnCansaco.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View button) {
            btnCansaco.setSelected(!button.isSelected());
            if (button.isSelected()) {
                dal.inserIntoRelMotivos(id,6);
            } else {

            }
        }
    });

    btnSono.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View button) {
            btnSono.setSelected(!button.isSelected());
            if (button.isSelected()) {
                dal.inserIntoRelMotivos(id,7);
            } else {

            }
        }
    });

    Next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
```

In each button.setOnClickListner, i want to use the id from the last activity, but its always 0. I tried to display the table and its always 0.

**Method "InserIntoRegSintomas"**

```
public void insertIntoRegSintomas(Sintoma Sintoma) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("Sintoma", Sintoma.getSintoma()); // recolhe o sintoma
    values.put("Dinicio", Sintoma.getDInicio());
    values.put("Hinicio", Sintoma.getHInicio());
    values.put("Dfim", Sintoma.getDFim());
    values.put("Hfim", Sintoma.getHFim());
    values.put("Intensidade", Sintoma.getIntensidade());
    this.db.insert("Reg_sintomas", null, values);
}
```

**Method InsertIntoRelMotivo**

```
  public void inserIntoRelMotivos (long Sintoma, long Motivo) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("id_sintoma", Sintoma);
    values.put("id_motivo", Motivo);
    this.db.insert("Sintoma_motivos", null, values);
}
```

Comment: What does s.getId() return ? Because I think it is not an Intent issue.

Comment: Yeah, im not sure if that is return something.. in my hope it would return the current id of the object.

Comment: You must use logs to see what the method returns and get back to us to answer :) OR change 'id' to '5' when you putExtra and check if the Intent does his job to send data.

Comment: I changed  long id = s.getId(); to long int = 5; and this value is not passing in the intent. Any tought ?

Comment: Maybe getLongExtra ? I think it is a type cast issue between int and long. You put a long value as int extra...

Comment: Still 0, but can be  s.getId(), that is doing nothing, any thought how to get the id ?

Comment: If you forget the Intent part of your project, tell us what is the value of id. You can use logs to see it.